# How do you double space text and keep the text alignment at the top?

Tags: html, css

I would like to have some text single spaced and some text double spaced.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.single-space {
  line-height: 1;
}
.double-space {
  line-height: 2;
}
```

```html
<p class="single-space">Default single-spaced line.</p>
<p class="double-space">Default paragraph of double-spaced text. With several sentences and lots of beautiful words to describe many awesome things.</p>
<p class="single-space">One more single-spaced line.</p>
<p class="double-space">Another paragraph of double-spaced text. With several sentences and lots of beautiful words to describe many awesome things</p>

<br /><p><b>Result should look like this:</b></p><br />

<p class="single-space">This is what it should look like to have a single spaced line followed by a double spaced line.<br>This is what a double spaced line<br /><br />should look like. Notice that it <br /><br />follows directly after the single<br /><br />spaced line.<br /><br />And finally a single spaced line following the last double spaced line reveals a full space between the two.</p>
```

The problem is that the double-spaced text becomes somewhat vertically centered adding extra white space on the top of the paragraph and decreasing the amount of white space after a double-space paragraph. The result is awkward gaps between single-space and double-space paragraphs. Ideally, the text of a double-space paragraph should be aligned at the top of the container so that the visual effect is identical to what would occur if a break element were used after ever single line of text.

Comment: .double-space { font-size: 1rem; margin-top: -0.5rem } ?

Comment: Just as an FYI, using `line-height` is the officially recommended way of double spacing: http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/C21.html

Comment: @JeremyHarris Ya, too bad it looks horrible and completely wrong, otherwise works perfect. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This now should work with `position: relative` and top vertical alignment `top: -.5em`. The `.5em` is half of `2em - 1em`, where `1em` is the default font size.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.single-space {
  line-height: 1;
}
.double-space {
  line-height: 2;
  position: relative; 
  top: -.5em;
}
```

```html
<p class="single-space">Default single-spaced line.</p>
<p class="single-space">Default single-spaced line.</p>
<p class="double-space">Default paragraph of double-spaced text. With several sentences and lots of beautiful words to describe many awesome things.</p>

<p class="single-space">One more single-spaced line.</p>
<p class="double-space">Another paragraph of double-spaced text. With several sentences and lots of beautiful words to describe many awesome things</p>

<br /><p><b>Result should look like this:</b></p><br />

<p class="single-space">This is what it should look like to have a single spaced line followed by a double spaced line.<br>This is what a double spaced line<br /><br />should look like. Notice that it <br /><br />follows directly after the single<br /><br />spaced line.<br /><br />And finally a single spaced line following the last double spaced line reveals a full space between the two.</p>
```

Comment: So simple. I love it.